# Customizing a survey in Sharepoint

Tags: survey-list

I need to customize the survey functionality provided by SharePoint to show/hide questions depending on what was the answer to the previous question. I know about branching logic but the problem is that it creates page breaks. I need to make the next question appear/disappear much like what is happening here on this page - http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=2402620 The questions should get appended as the user keeps on answering.

[image]

Is this possible in SharePoint?